# Visibility.js doesn't fire state change

Tags: reactjs, visibilitychange

In my react project have [visibility.js](https://www.npmjs.com/package/visibilityjs) package imported, which I am using to re-render page if user opens web view from background and more then 5 min is passed, inside one of my hook I have simple implementation:

```
useEffect(() => {
 let initialTime = 0
 const limit = 5 * 60 // 5 min.
 const listener = Visibility.change(function (e, state) {
   if (Visibility.hidden()) {
     initialTime = (new Date().getTime()) / 1000
   } else {
     const currentTime = (new Date().getTime()) / 1000
     updatePage()
    }
  }
})

 return () => {
   Visibility.unbind(listener)
 }
}, [])
```

This is working if you open in 10 min, 1 hour or so, but noticed that it doesn't work after a long time leaving the web in the background, like overnight... I am testing on IPhone 12, V14.6.
Did some research, but couldn't find any ideas on this particular case, maybe someone had the same issue and can share your experience, thanks.